# Canvas.js doughnut chart thickness

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts, canvasjs

I'm currently working on some **doughnut** charts using Canvas.JS, and I'm not able to find a proper way to set the chart's thickness.

The docs are pretty extensive (you can go [over here](http://canvasjs.com/docs/) to check them out) but I can't seem to find a proper solution for my "problem".

Right now I'm generating the chart with the following code:

```
CanvasJS.addColorSet('circColors', [
  '#7583B2',
  '#E6866A'
]);

var circChartOptions = {
  animationEnabled: true,
  colorSet: 'circColors',
  data: [
    {
      labelFontColor: '#9EA4AC',
      labelFontFamily: 'Lato, sans-serif',
      labelFontWeight: 'normal',
      indexLabelLineColor: 'white',
      type: 'doughnut',
      startAngle:-90,
      toolTipContent: '{label}: {y} - <strong>#percent%</strong>',
      indexLabel: '{label} #percent%',
      dataPoints: [
        { y: 37.47, label: 'Mobile' },
        { y: 62.53, label: 'Desktop' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

$('#circChart').CanvasJSChart(circChartOptions);
```

Does Canvas.JS even provide a way to control the chart's thickness? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data: [
{
  labelFontColor: '#9EA4AC',
  labelFontFamily: 'Lato, sans-serif',
  labelFontWeight: 'normal',
  indexLabelLineColor: 'white',
  type: 'doughnut',
  innerRadius: "85%",
  startAngle:-90,
  toolTipContent: '{label}: {y} - <strong>#percent%</strong>',
  indexLabel: '{label} #percent%',
  dataPoints: [
    { y: 37.47, label: 'Mobile' },
    { y: 62.53, label: 'Desktop' }
  ]
}
```

use innerRadius to control the tickness

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's hard coded, so you'll have to change it in the canvasjs file.

```
var widthPercentage = 0.60;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, sadly I can't find anything related to widthPercentage in the CanvasJS .js file :(

Comment: Did you look in the non minified version canvasjs.js (not canvasjs.min.js)?

Comment: You were correct, in the non-minified version of the file it's pretty easy to find. Thanks a lot!